# leafR error: no applicable method for 'readLAS' applied to an object of class "c('LAS', 'Spatial')

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

First, I read a LAS file into R using the readLAS() function from the lidR package:

```r
test_las <-readLAS("C:/Users/LAS files/file.las")
```

I am now attempting to use functions from the `leafR` package on the LAS file like so:

```r
#Create a dataframe of the 3D voxels information (xyz) with Leaf Area Density values from las file
lads <- lad.voxels(file.las, grain.size = 1, k = 1)
```

and it produces this error:

```r
#> Error in UseMethod("readLAS", files) : 
#>   no applicable method for 'readLAS' applied to an object of class "c('LAS', 'Spatial')"
```

What do I need to do to prevent this error?

Comment: According to the documentation of  `leafR` the function expects a path to the las file. Not a LAS object

Comment: Where is the `leafR` package? I can't see it on CRAN. [Edit] its been removed: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leafR/index.html